# Unable to docker login into azure container registry

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-registry

We are using docker swarm for windows and have several swarms. Most of them works great, but when making a new one, we are now currently failing the docker login. The code used to login is:

```
echo "$(acrPassword)" | docker login --username $(acrUsername) --password-stdin  $(acrServer)
```

This line works perfectly well on other swarms, but on this new one, it fails with the following error:

```
[error]docker : Error response from daemon: Get https://myaccount.azurecr.io/v2/: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.
```

here is the result from docker version:

`Server: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       2ee0c57608
  Built:            11/13/2019 07:58:51
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false`

Edit: Found the issue, it was an older version of windows. Changed the Windows verison and fixed the issue.

Comment: Which password do you use for the ACR?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to login in to your ACR using the Azure CLI?

```
az acr login --name acrServer
```

Comment: yes, I did that. While the login works, when I deploy a service in the swarm, it does not find the image (which i double checked and is present in the acr)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting prompt for `username` and `password`, make sure that you have enabled "admin login" on your Azure Portal.

Follow this link for instructions-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication?tabs=azure-cli#admin-account

Then login again with username and password. Then hopefully, you will see the message `Login Succeeded`.